# Passing an array of Object using Provider in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, provider

I have fetched the following API from `https://api.github.com/users` and was trying to share the array via provider using React. How can I achieve this ?

```
export const dataArray = createContext();

function ApiData() {

    // Assign the Array and set it an empty array
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [loadDataState, setloadDataState] = useState(false) // Initates a loadData variable to set initial state as false

    const baseUrl = 'https://api.github.com/users'

    useEffect( () => {
        axios.get(baseUrl)
            .then((Response) => 
            {
                console.log('========== Github Api  ==========')
                setUsers(Response.data)
                console.log('Json Array', Response.data)
                console.log('User Array', users);
                console.log('=================================')
                setloadDataState(true);
            })
            .catch(error => {console.error(error)})
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <>
            <dataArray.Provider>
                
            </dataArray.Provider>
        </>
    )
}

export default ApiData
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use state providers, I would sugget for you to use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) (if you're working on a project with complexe states), if not you could use [Contexte API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for a simple logic.

If you want to just pass the Array to a component you could pass it in props, something like this:

```
return (
<YourComponent users={users}/>
)
```

in YourComponent.js

```
function YourComponent(props) {
return (
<p>props.users</p>
)
}
export default YourComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use react context [`Provider`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider) can have a `value` property which will receive the data which will be provide to all sub component which use the context.

```
<MyContext.Provider value={/* some value */}>
```

In case the `value` props isn't provide the value which will be provide to sub component is the value which was provide when you call `React.createContext`

```
const MyContext = React.createContext(defaultValue);
```

Comment: What is the difference between using Provider and just passing the the array as a prop?

Comment: With Provider which is part of context you wont have to pass each time data as props to each sub component when need, you can just use the context directly and you will have access to the data which was provided on the `MyContext.Provider` wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, isn't that less efficient? Maybe cleaner code, but makes more sense to just pass the variables which will be used..